# Project generator with specific ng/nrwl versions

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, nrwl-nx, nrwl

Sadly we are, for several reasons, not able to use the angular 12 version, therefore we do not want to use the current versions of ng and nrwl.

I haven't found documentation about how to generate a project with a specific version of ng. It seems that it always uses the most corrent version. But we need to use an older version (`^10.0.0`).

What I do is this:

```
yarn global add @nrwl/cli@10.0.6
yarn create nx-workspace myProject --style=scss --preset=empty --nx-cloud=false --cli=angular
```

But this will use the `12.6.5` version:

```
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.0",
    "@nrwl/tao": "12.6.5",
    "@nrwl/cli": "12.6.5",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "12.6.5",
    "@types/node": "14.14.33",
    "dotenv": "~10.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~9.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
```

I like to avoid all ^12 versions and get instead the ^10 versions of these libraries.

When I try (I am not sure if this is correct syntax): `yarn create nx-workspace@10.0.6 myProject --style=scss --preset=empty --nx-cloud=false --cli=angular` it does not succed.

I get an error, like:

```
success Installed "create-nx-workspace@10.0.6" with binaries:
      - create-nx-workspace
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/create-nx-workspace@10.0.6: No such file or directory
error Command failed.
```

If anybody could tell me how to execute a create nx-workspace command with a specific version, I would be thankfull.

Comment: Which angular cli version are you using?

Comment: Remove your global angular cli from local machine. Then run `npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.0` to install angular cli version 10.

Comment: thx, but this does not work, I tried it already. I guess the versions are set via the `nx-workspace` script.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create/), the command `yarn create nx-workspace` will *always* install latest [**create-nx-workspace**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-nx-workspace) and run its bin. This is why you're always seeing it install version **12.x**.

Instead, you can split up and perform these steps manually. Note that we're running the global bin directly, *not* using `yarn create` in this case:

```sh
yarn global add create-nx-workspace@^10.0.0
create-nx-workspace myProject --style=scss --preset=empty --nx-cloud=false --cli=angular
```

Answer (score 0):

As others are suggesting, in order to generate angular with specific versions (lets say v11 or v8) you would have to first uninstall the global version you have installed.

> I'll add it with npm examples as this is what I know; if yarn examples are provided I can update the answer at a later time.

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`

Next you would want to find the particular released version and install that

`npm install -g @angular/cli@v11.0.0`

from this point on your global CLI reference will be the installed version.

**Bonus tip**, if you're working with many projects that run on different versions of angular you can target the `ng` of the *node_modules* folder via a command like `npm run-script ng XYZ`.